Stop/Cancel/Delete Cloud Run Scheduler Job
I am have created a cloud run job scheduler and due to some issues, i want to cancel/stop it and there is an option to cancel/delete it but it is disable for me. How to enable it. Please let me know.

To be able to delete Cloud Scheduler Jobs, you need to have the cloudscheduler.jobs.delete permission.
A default role that has this permission is Cloud Scheduler Admin (but also Editor has this)
